# Validate ExtJS CheckboxGroup checked boxes

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, checkbox, extjs4

Using ExtJS 4, I have a `Ext.form.CheckboxGroup` and I want to do validation on this checkbox group like 'valid only when 1, 2, or 3 checkboxes checked' out of a set of maybe 10 checkboxes.  There is an existing `allowBlank: false` config option I can set to ensure the CheckboxGroup has at least one checkbox checked.  I'd like to get essentially the same functionality but with a custom validator function so that I can specify my own criteria.

How can I accomplish this?

Looking at the docs and code, I don't see a clear way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to extend standard `Ext.form.CheckboxGroup` by overwriting `validate()` method to return true when some number of checkboxes are checked.

I don't see anything more standard, but it should not be complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using one more attribute in config object to specify how many checkboxes or array of ids of checkboxes need checking. If you want the validation is just like a trigger (enable/disable), you can handle it in the `change` event handler.

In case you want to use validation with error message and/or make the component reusable, it is better to follow sha's way above.